# How to send XML datasource object as parameter to JasperReports fill method

Tags: java, xml, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm using JasperReports within a java application using iReport to create the templates. For one particular report I would like to pass an xml object as the datasource to the report machine. I've been able to create an xml file on the file system in my java application first and then use that as the datasource and it all works great. But the write/read overhead seems like a performance hit and certainly slows down the process noticeably.

Is it possible to send the whole xml datasource itself as a parameter to the jasper fill methods and bypass the disk write/read steps?

(This is a desktop app not web based).

Thanks in advance,
Jeff

Comment: You can look at this [XML Data Source Example](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xmldatasource/index.html#xmldatasource)

Comment: Yes. That's exactly how I was able to get it working. But jasper requires a path to an xml file. Hence the file writing overhead I'm trying to avoid.

*NOTE: I don't think it's possible so I've re-writen it to use a customdatasource Object instead.

Comment: @jeff can you please share your final solution?